# How to set a value equal to one variable for another instance variable

Tags: java, class, instance-variables

Given the following declaration:

```
class Student {
    private double GPA;
    private String name;
    Student s = new Student();
    public void setGPA(double GPA) {
        this.GPA = GPA;
    }enter code here
    public double getGPA() {
        return GPA;
    }
}
```

Question: Assuming that s is an instance (object) of the class Student, what is the statement to assign 3.5 to the GPA for s?

Comment: I've tried the following     s.GPA = 3.5;

Comment: lol you are not on the right path for sure!

Comment: doesn't it have something to do with replacing the "this"? So that the GPA can change for the s variable?

Comment: You are creating instance of the same within  that class! Why?

Comment: Isn't it so that I can assign the s to the GPA of 3.5?

Comment: That's not the problem , the problem is that you have need `S` in a class from where you want to set values , in this case in other class.

Comment: So I would have to move the s into the public class that returns the GPA and then have it set to 3.5 from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, Your student class can be used to create object and we need some reference to that object in order to change the values. Here `s` which is called instance of the student, that `s` refers to your student. When you write `new` word in java, it means you are creating some new object(in this case a student).

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setGPA(3.5); //set Gpa
        System.out.println(s.getGPA());
    }

}
    class Student {
        private double GPA;
        private String name;


        public void setGPA(double GPA) {
            this.GPA = GPA;
        }


        public double getGPA() {
            return GPA;

    }

}
```

Or you can use constructor in student class to initialize `Gpa` when creating an object like this. However you can use setter and getter later to manipulate the values.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Student s = new Student(5,"Khan");
        System.out.println("The given Gpa is " + s.getGPA() + " and name is " + s.getName());
        s.setGPA(3.5); //change Gpa
        System.out.println(s.getGPA()+ "The gpa has been changed");
    }

}
    class Student {
        private double GPA;
        private String name;
        public Student(double Gp,String Name) {
            this.GPA = Gp;
            this.name = Name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setGPA(double GPA) {
            this.GPA = GPA;
        }


        public double getGPA() {
            return GPA;

    }

}
```

Comment: ohhh, i didn't know what set even existed, I thought that you had to use = in some way to set it up. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it

Comment: @RabbidOtter62845 you can't say something like this: `Student s = new Student()` in your student class btw it happends at beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question as written doesn't make a lot of sense.

The problem is that the code as written will "blow up" if you ever attempt to create a `Student` object.  Your `Student` class has a field `s` which is attempts to initialize to *another* `Student` object.  Which attempts to create another one.  Which attempts to create another one ....

You get the picture?

Your `s` should not be there.  It makes no sense for a `Student` to have a field that is itself a `Student`

That means that your question about how to set one of the fields of an object that cannot be successfully instantiated (see above) doesn't make sense.

---

Here is a version that *does* make sense:

```
class Student {
    private double GPA;
    private String name;

    public void setGPA(double GPA) {
        this.GPA = GPA;
    }

    public double getGPA() {
        return GPA;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setGPA(3.5);   // This is the statement!
        System.out.println("Score is " + s.getGPA());
    }
}
```

> ohhh, i didn't know what set even existed

Your code explicitly declares the `setGPA` method ... so of course it exists!

I think you need to go back to the tutorial, lecture notes, textbook, whatever that you are leaning from, and read up on the structure of a Java class.  What fields are, what methods are, what constructors are .... and how to use them.